# autoupdate nvim terminal

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to make the nvim terminal always automatically scroll down so you can see the latest messages? For example I have my vim editor setup like this

[image]

On the button half of the screen I have a horizontal split nvim terminal window. However I always have to manually switch to that window and scroll down to see the latest terminal outputs. Is it possible to make the terminal window scroll down automatically just like it does in vscode?

Comment: What exactly is being displayed in the terminal window? I assume that's a runtime log for a service or something like that.....? I'm surprised to hear that it doesn't scroll along with it. Did a quick test in my vim and it tracked along with it just fine. I also tried `tail -f somefile` and had similar results. Please provide specific details if you would.

Comment: I have my node server running in that terminal and its basicly just output from my server like console outputs or error messages

Comment: I just noticed "nvim". If you're using neovim you should call that out. Doesn't necessarily mean it's the cause but it's a relevant detail. Terminal implementations in vim vs nvim are non-trivially different.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just adjusted my original question

Comment: No problem! And welcome to Vi/Vim SE.

Comment: Which version of neovim are you using? I had [a PR merged last year](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/10700) for this exact same problem and I can't reproduce your issue in `NVIM v0.5.0-563`

Comment: NVIM v0.4.3. This could be it! Thank you, as soon as I Update my nvim I'll let you know if it works